# Wpf DataGrid Repeated Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want a datagrid which has repeated columns in it as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

This is just one datagrid and colums are repeated.
How can we do this with wpf windows datagrid?

Thanks,

Comment: Data in repeated columns are different? If so, then the data source one for each column? Or not?

Comment: just one datasource. Yes data in repeated columns is different.

Comment: do you use mvvm and wpf bindings?

Comment: yes i use mvvm and wpf bindings

Answer (score 3):

I tried to implement your problem in the following way.

There is a certain amount of data that must be defined in the columns. But these few, and we want them to define a repeating column in the `DataGrid`.

Suppose it is known, at least *approximately* the number of columns and rows. Then be the data `cube` to be set in the `DataGrid`. Below is a my example with my comments.

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridDynamicAddCol.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="DynamicColumnDataGrid" Loaded="DynamicColumnDataGrid_Loaded" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    // Create class with data
    // Note: Each parameter contains a list of values for it.
    public class Person
    {
        public Person() 
        {
            FirstName = new List<string>();
            SecondName = new List<string>();
            Sample = new List<string>();
        }

        public List<string> FirstName { get; set; }

        public List<string> SecondName { get; set; }

        public List<string> Sample { get; set; }
    }

    // Number of columns
    const Int32 COLS = 3;

    // Number of rows
    const Int32 ROWS = 3;

    // Number repeats
    const Int32 RPTS = 3;

    // Array of headers
    string[] HeadersArray = new string[COLS] 
    { 
        "FirstName", 
        "SecondName", 
        "Sample"
    };

    // Array of values: Depends on the number of columns and rows
    // Note: The number of repetitions you can specify smaller amounts of data
    // If you specify more, then this place will be empty cells
    string[, ,] ValuesArray = new string[, ,] 
    {
        {
            { "Andy", "Caufmann", "Artist"},
            { "Sam", "Fisher", "Spy"},
            { "Ben", "Affleck", "Actor"}
        },
        {
            { "Jim", "Gordon", "Sniper"},
            { "Maria", "Gray", "Cleaner"},
            { "Katy", "Parry", "Artist"}
        },
        {
            { "Jack", "Rider", "Hunter"},
            { "Sven", "Vath", "DJ"},
            { "Paul", "Kalkbrenner", "Super DJ"}
        }
    };

    private List<Person> OnePerson;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnePerson = new List<Person>();

        // Create the columns
        for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; cols++)
        {
            OnePerson.Add(new Person());
        }

        // Create the rows
        for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; cols++)
        {
            for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; rows++)
            {
                OnePerson[rows].FirstName.Add(ValuesArray[cols, rows, 0]);
                OnePerson[rows].SecondName.Add(ValuesArray[cols, rows, 1]);
                OnePerson[rows].Sample.Add(ValuesArray[cols, rows, 2]);
            }
        }

        DynamicColumnDataGrid.ItemsSource = OnePerson;
    }

    private void DynamicColumnDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create dynamically the columns and rows
        for (int rpts = 0; rpts < RPTS; rpts++ )
        {
            for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; cols++)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn MyTextColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
                MyTextColumn.Header = HeadersArray[cols];

                // Binding values from HeadersArray
                MyTextColumn.Binding = new Binding(String.Format("{0}[{1}]", 
                    new object[]
                    {
                        HeadersArray[cols], rpts
                    }
                ));

                // Add column in DataGrid
                DynamicColumnDataGrid.Columns.Add(MyTextColumn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Output`

The number of repetitions - `3`:

[image]

The number of repetitions - `2`:

[image]

If you specify the number of repetitions is greater than it is in the cube, you will see a picture:

[image]

That is quite logical, since the relevant data are not *available*.

*`Note`*: To use the `Binding` a `ViewModel`, you need to determine the appropriate lists / collection, set them to the elements and assemble them into a single data cube. In my example, *static* data, but you need to determine the source of the data, the amount of data, then set them aside and put them in a data cube. I think, without a data cube, it will be difficult to implement something of this kind (I tried different options, the use of the `Converter`, `Binding` directly from the array, etc).

Comment: How can we apply this if we can use binding from viewmodel?

Comment: It all depends on your data and the source. *Static* or *dynamic* data. The example was *static*. In my example, `Binding` loops through the data, and inserts for each header, the value of the array. The title name matches the name of the values for `Binding`.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you place 3 (or more) datagrids horizontally and bind the data using paging.. I mean first 10 (n) records to grid 1, next 10 (n) records to grid 2 like wise.

you can use **Skip** and **Take** methods available in LINQ to do paging...

```
record.Skip((page - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by manually adding repeated columns to your `Datagrid`. Headers don't need to be unique:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="header1" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="header2" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="header1" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="header2" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: But it binds the same data. If you look at my example carefully, you can see the data is not the same  per repeated columns.

Comment: Almost sounds like a job that would involve a wrap panel

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the values were different. By looking at your picture, I think what you are trying to do is to have rows 1-8 under the first set of columns, rows 9-16 under the second set of columns, etc? Is the number of rows fixed? will it always be a multiple of 3?

Comment: yes we can say like this. But not always 3. It must be how many i want

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure of what you asking, but if I'm correct you want to have the "same" column repeated with different data.

You can do this, but not in the way you think. This is the purpose for having a view model, to encapsulate data in a way for your view to read it. What you actually want is columns that have the same header and styling, including for it's items, but that binds to different properties in the view model.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Controls:DataGrid x:Key="YourDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
        <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="SecondName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>   
        </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</Controls:DataGrid>
```

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource YourDataGrid}" DataContext="{Binding Path=FirstDataContext}"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource YourDataGrid}" DataContext="{Binding Path=SecondDataContext}"></ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```